# Localize strings with components in react native

Tags: react-native, localization

I'm working happily with localization and it is working fine, but I encountered a problem and I want to put all in one string instead splitting the paragraph in several strings: this is the part on the view I want to translate:

```
<View>
        <BodyOne style={styles.text}>
          By login into our app, you're accepting our{' '}
          <Text style={styles.link} onPress={() => alert('terms')}>
            terms and conditions
          </Text>{' '}
          and{' '}
          <Text style={styles.link} onPress={() => alert('privacy')}>
            Privacy Policy
          </Text>
          .
        </BodyOne>
```

In my en.json file, I'm trying to put it like this:

```
{
"common": {
    "test": "By login into our app, you're accepting our <Text style={styles.link} onPress={() => alert('terms')}>
    terms and conditions</Text> and <Text style={styles.link} onPress={() => alert('privacy')}>
    Privacy Policy</Text>.",
}
```

But this throws me an "EOF error" in the Expo client.

If possible, my function to translate is t('key'). How can I put all that text into the JSON and make possible to translate such things?

Comment: Ciao, what library are you using? react-native-localize?

Comment: Ciao Giovanni, I'm using expo-localization, i18next. And I am following this tutorial https://phrase.com/blog/posts/react-native-i18n-with-expo-and-i18next-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, unfortunately you cannot put `<Text>` in a translation using `expo-localization, i18next`. This library does not parse react-native components like `<Text>`. Maybe for security reason: allow something like that could be a code injection that could be harmful. But I'm not a security expert so take my last sentence as a personal opinion.

So basically I think your first solution is the best one.

Comment: And what about variables? like:

subtitle={`${group.members} + 'members'}

to 

subtitle={t(n: ${group.members}, 'profile:members'}

Comment: Yes, parametrize a string is allowed in `expo-localization` (and I massively use).

Comment: How is it done? in the Expo docs they don't explain this.

Comment: You could use [interpolation](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help you. If you mark answer as correct I would really appreciate it. Have a nice day :)